# How to test an abstract class with PHPunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Lets assume I have a file at `/var/www/project/calculator.class.php`

and here is the class

```
namespace App/Module/Calculator; 

abstract class calculator{

 static property $add; 

 static property $result; 

 function add($val_a, $val_b){
    return $a + $b; 
 }

}
```

I would like to create a test case, for the above class, but it seems impossible to test it. I am stuck at the very basic stage.

```
require '/var/www/project/calculator.class.php';

 class CalculatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testAbstactDatabaseClassExists()
    {

       $this->assertEquals(is_object('Database'), 1);
      $this->assertEquals(true, in_array('Calculator', get_declared_classes()));

    }

 }
```

No matter what I do, there does not seem to be a way to test, the class and it's contents.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Your class is syntatically incorrect.  There's no property keyword, and your add method either has to use $this (for instance variables) or self:: or static:: (for class variables)

Comment: Don't test abstracts, test concretes.... if necessary create a little stub extension class for your abstract so that you can instantiate it for testing

Comment: @MarkBaker while in many situations this is sound advice, if there is a lot of concrete classes extending some abstract base class it is much better to write tests for abstract class and test specialised functionality of concrete classes in their tests. Otherwise you will end up with a lot of duplicated tests.

Comment: You only need to test the abstract methods once, you don't need to tests those methods for other concrete classes that extend it

Comment: @MarkBaker I have never heard of a concrete class in PHP. I assume you are referring to stepozer's answer? Just create a an extending class, and access it that way?

Comment: @spartak - a `concrete class` is a general term for a class that can be instantiated, ie. a class that isn't abstract - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete or http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~jsa/UMLJavaShortCourse09/CGOutput/Unit9/unit9(0809)/page_03.htm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When testing abstract classes, you may use the Mock features of PHPUnit. An example for the add method would be as following:

```
public function testAdd() {
    /* @var $calculator \App\Module\Calculator\calculator|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject */
    $calculator = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('App\Module\Calculator\calculator')
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $result = $calculator->add(13, 29);
    $this->assertEquals(42, $result);
}
```

For further information about Mocking, please refer to the [PHPUnit manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html).

Comment: What if the abstract class has a constructor that requires an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way - create child class from calculator, and use child in test (but it is not good practice):

```
class CalculatorChildForTest extends calculator
{
}
// your test here use CalculatorChildForTest
class CalculatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
```

Comment: Two class in one class file. Not my cup of tee.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of PHP anonymous classes. They were introduced in 5.3. They may not be suitable if your abstract class has lots of abstract methods.

```
protected function createConcrete(...$args): YourAbstractClass
{
    return new class(...$args) extends YourAbstractClass {
        public function concreteImplementation(): void
        {

        }
    };
}
```